# Accessing PHP variable as URL in JQuery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am experiencing some problems with having the Ajax request function/method in JQuery recognizing a PHP-variable from outside the script code. What I am trying to do is using the variable **$live_update_url** as the url-argument in the Ajax code. The code below is not working, but if I hard code the value of the url there are no problems. So it should be the variable itself that is not accessed. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function ajaxd()    {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: <?php print($live_update_url);?>,
                        type: "get",
                        data: {live_time: 'value'}, 
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#local_time').html(data.live_time);
                      }
                    });
```

Comment: do this  `url: "<?php echo $live_update_url;?>"` . `"` is neccesery

Comment: Just tried the echo function too and it's not working either for some reason

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the quotes around the URL value in your JSON.

Make sure that the value returned by the `$live_update_url` includes quotes or try this:

```
function ajaxd()    {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php print($live_update_url);?>",
                    type: "get",
                    data: {live_time: 'value'}, 
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#local_time').html(data.live_time);
                  }
                });
```

Comment: You're right @Tim, the quotes marks are missing but even with them there it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

Used the following definition of $live_update_url in the PHP code:

$live_update_url = "'http://localhost/projectName/api/time.php?g_id=".$g_id."'";

This string already includes single quotes within the double quotes. Then I used the echo <<<_END-construct and just added the following line in the Ajax request:

**url: $live_update_url**